# how to compare date (in query criteria) in pyral

Tags: python, pyral

I have a requirement to find the tasks which are not updated.

The criteria looks like :

```
'iteration.Name = \"iterationName\" and State!=Completed and LastUpdateDate<'+str(datetime.datetime.now())+"'"
```

This would result in:

```
iteration.Name = "iterationName" and State!=Completed and LastUpdateDate<'2015-12-27 20:17:08.769000'
```

I didn't get any results.

The rally task object has the `LastUpdateDate` as `2015-12-16T09:54:30.600Z 8.0`

How do I compare the `LastUpdateDate` in the query criterion?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with multiple arguments in the end I had to add brackets to get it to work.

```
(('iteration.Name = \"iterationName\") AND (State!=Completed)) AND (LastUpdateDate<'+str(datetime.datetime.now())+"'")
```

There's probably too many brackets in there, the key thing I think was to get a bracket around the first two conditions; if adding another condition it would look something like this

```
((((condition1) AND (condition2)) AND (condition3)) AND (condition4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Question was asked ages ago, but might be useful for people looking for using queries with dates in **pyral**.

There are several issues with the code in the question:

1. `datetime.datetime.now()` will probably not return a date in the format needed by Rally, so it is better to use `strftime` to get the proper format
2. Multiple conditions need to have correct set of parentheses; for example: `((((condition1) AND (condition2)) AND (condition3)) AND (condition4))`
3. `LastUpdateDate` will necessarily be previous to current date (unless the users have been able to jump to the future).
4. It is better to put dates with double quotes (`"`) instead of single quotes (`'`)

Here is the code I came for identifying tasks that have not been updated in the last 5 days and are not completed.

```
iter_name = "2018-Iteration-4"
five_days_ago = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=5)
str_date = five_days_ago.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
tasks_not_updated = rally.get(
    'Task',
    query = '(((iteration.Name = "%s")'
            ' and (State != Completed))'
            ' and (LastUpdateDate < "%s"))' % (iter_name, str_date)
)
for task in tasks_not_updated:
    print("%s (%s)" % (task.Name, task.State))
```